# pair images with string inside arrays using android

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, kotlin, object

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var imageView: ImageView
    lateinit var button: Button
    lateinit var textView: TextView

    val lImages: IntArray = intArrayOf(
        R.drawable.android_background1,
        R.drawable.android_background2,
        R.drawable.android_background3,
    )

    private val lQuotes = arrayOf(
        "text1",
        "text2",
        "text3"
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val random = Random
            imageView.setImageResource(lImages[random.nextInt(lImages.size)])
            val randomQ = (0 until(lQuotes.size)).random()
            textView.text = lQuotes[randomQ]
        }
    }
}
```

On every press of the button, the output on the display shows a random image with a random sentence. Using two arrays is the only way I knew how to get them both to output at each press of the button.

But how would I alter it so that after each button press, the output will still be random, except that the sentences will appear with its corresponding image?

Comment: You need generate only one random index . and use this index for both image and text . I assume that images and sentences are in index relation. i.e for first image first sentence will appear and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but how would I make a random index that includes both text and images? 

I'm not very familiar with kotlin but I can tell making an object of an array is different than in java~

Comment: Its not about kotlin and java . Since both of your array are of same size so just generate a single random number with `val randomIndex = (0 untill (lQuotes.size)).random()`. and use this randomIndex to get image and sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to create a separate class that holds the image and quote. In this manner, you'll only need one array with objects from that class.

Another useful feature of Kotlin is extension functions.

```
fun Array<ImageHolder>.getNextRandom(): ImageHolder {
    return this[(0..this.size - 1).random()]
}
```

This method will return a random item when called on an `ImageHolder` array.

Here's the full code for that:

```
data class ImageHolder(val image: Int, val quote: String)

fun Array<ImageHolder>.getNextRandom(): ImageHolder {
    return this[(0..this.size - 1).random()]
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var imageView: ImageView
    lateinit var button: Button
    lateinit var textView: TextView

    val images: Array<ImageHolder> = arrayOf(
        ImageHolder(R.drawable.android_background1,"text1"),
        ImageHolder(R.drawable.android_background2,"text2"),
        ImageHolder(R.drawable.android_background3,"text3"),
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val randomImage = images.getNextRandom();
            imageView.setImageResource(randomImage.image)
            textView.text = randomImage.quote
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 1: updated extension function

Comment: Thank you very much for you response! The code you provided worked perfectly!
Also, if you don't mind, could you explain how a separate class would hold the images and quotes, then have an array in the main class access it?

It's okay if you don't, the edit to the code was already a great help.
Thanks again!

Comment: In Kotlin, you can create simple classes that have no behavior using data classes. It's a good thing to "bundle" properties that belong together in their own class. I did this with the `data class ImageHolder.`

That class has two properties: an image which is an Int (id of the image probably), and the quote as String. Read more on [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html)

After defining this class, create an array that has objects derived from this class. This way, when accessing an element from the array, you have access to every property inside the accessed object.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information, I will read more on data classes and use them to the best of my ability. Thanks again!